# active menu item that triggers mega-menu is not highlighted

Tags: css, wordpress, megamenu

I have a menu item called "Products" seen here: https://digitalcloud.co.za/2ic/2ic-overview/ which triggers a mega menu. However when selecting any page from that mega-menu the "Products" tab in the menu does not show as being active (orange in color), have created a css class but still doesnt work.

Created a css class megpro but its not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "current_page_item" class to the active li tag (menu-item-5381).

Also, if you want to highlight the active sub link too, add the style:

```
li.current-menu-item > a {
color:#e78900 !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, not sure if its correct - but unfortunately nothing?

.megpro>li.current_page_item>a {
color: #e78900 !important;
}

#menu-item-5381>li.current_page_item>a {
    color: #e78900 !important;
}

li.current-menu-item > a {
    color:blue !important;
}

Comment: just li.current_page_item > a { color: #e78900 !important; } , without megpro.

Comment: For your main question ignore css, just add current-menu-item class to your html.
- Try adding "current_page_item" class to the active li tag (menu-item-5381).